# Convert Switch True() Dax calculated column to M query custom colum

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I am having issues with my calculated column and the multiple tables I am joining. It is not filtering my visuals correctly. After researching it was recommended to use a custom column in the query instead but  I do not know where to start to convert the following DAX to M query.

```
overall = 
VAR skills =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( tsr_skill[ts_skill] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( tsr_skill, tsr_skill[ts_tsr] )
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        "JMSR" IN skills, "Senior",
        "JMOV" IN skills, "Over",
        "JMUN" IN skills, "Under",
        "JMRH" IN skills, "RHT",
        "MNT"
    )
```

Data structure in Query:

[image: 1]

How I would like the data to show in the Query instead of showing as a calculated column.

Preferred Output:

[image: 2]

Comment: A text sample of your existing data (or similar) along with a screenshot of your expected results (and an explanation of the logic, if relevant) would be helpful.

Comment: I just added the screenshots. In short the logic would be to assign an overall skill for each distinct tsr. If the tsr has JMSR in their list of skill then it would assign them as senior, if they don't have that skill it would go to the next option of JMOV and assign them as an Over and so on.

Comment: You show "JMXX" assigned as "Over", but JMXX does not have the "JMOV" skill. Can you explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation, and the levels assigned in your DAX formula, it would seem that all should be assigned as "under".

*In your "Preferred Output" you do show `JMXX` being assigned as "Over", but that tsr does not include the `JMOV` skill*

If your written explanation is correct, and your Preferred Output screenshot incorrect based on the posted data, then, in PQ you can

- Group by `tsr`
- Create a custom aggregation returning the "overall" based on containing one of the skills listed in your DAX formula.

If that is not the case, please clarify how you are assigning "Over" to `JMXX`.

***Edit: M Code simplified***

**M Code**

```
let
    //Source = the data structure you show
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ts_tsr", type text}, {"ts_skill", type text}}),

//Group rows by tsr, then check if it has one of the defined skills
//If so, return the appropriate ranking.
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ts_tsr"}, {
        {"ALL", each _, type table [ts_tsr=nullable text, ts_skill=nullable text]},

        {"overall", each if List.Contains([ts_skill],"JMSR") then "Senior"
                        else if List.Contains([ts_skill],"JMOV") then "Over"
                        else if List.Contains([ts_skill],"JMUN") then "Under"
                        else if List.Contains([ts_skill],"JMRH") >=0 then "RHT"
                        else "MNT"}
       }),
       
//Then re-expand the table
    #"Expanded ALL" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "ALL", {"ts_skill"}, {"ts_skill"})
in
    #"Expanded ALL"
```

**Data**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Might be that there are more rows with `JMXX` than in the screenshot provided.

Comment: @Marcus Hopefully the case.  But I sure prefer examples where the results are congruent with the data.

Comment: I apologize as Marcus was correct my screenshot cut off the over skill showing for JMXX

Comment: @JennS  Does my solution work for you?  (except for the Count column for which you did not provide the logic).

Comment: This worked Ron!!! Thank you so much I have been struggling for a couple days on this!

Comment: @JennS I just edited the M Code to provide what is probably a more efficient function for the aggregation.  And if you provide the relevant logic, I could also easily compute the Count column in PQ